# Simple python program - stuck

Tags: python, list, integer, range

I'm writing this code where it says if the person I put has a high score or not.

It works fine when I put in a person within the list for example "Thor", however the program is not catching the error and not printing "no they don't have a top score" if the name isn't in the list.

```
Names = ['Ben', 'Thor', 'Zoe', 'Kate']
Max = 4
Current = 1
Found = False
PlayerName = input("What player are you looking for? ")
while (Found == False) and (Current <= Max):
    if Names[Current] == PlayerName:
        Found = True
    else:
        Current = Current + 1
if Found == True:
    print("Yes, they have a top Score")
else:
    print("No, They do not have a top score")
```

So if put in James for example it would input this error

```
if Names[Current] == PlayerName:
IndexError: list index out of range"
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: lists are zero based, change to `Current < Max` and you'll be running on 0, 1, 2, 3 (4 elements in total).

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly, what do i do? Close the question or?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I just see that you answered the question before than me in the comment. so I deleted my answer. :) please post it. its yours :)

Comment: @Abraham that's OK, you undo the deletion :) you posted a good explanation.

Comment: `if PlayerName in Names:` is a more succinct solution than a while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started your array index from `1` while in Python, C, C++ and a lot of languages, array indexes (such as lists) start from `0` and ends in `ArrayLength - 1`. Change your loop to:

```
while (Found == False) and (Current < Max):
                                    ↑
```

Answer (score 0):

`Max` should be 3 not 4.
Don't forget that arrays are 0 indexed, so `Names[3]` refers to the 4th element (and the last)

And start from 0 `Current=0`